# Nginx: make subdomain to not accept ssl request at all

Tags: nginx, ssl

Previously, when my site does not have SSL/https at all, trying to access it would fail. For example, curl would return:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Now that I have implemented SSL in a subdomain, I would like to simulate the previous behavior in all other domains.

For example: my https://api.example.com works as expected. But now visting https://www.example.com to would return 403.

```
# HTTPS server
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name api.example.com:

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://app;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  server_name _;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  deny all;
}
```

How should I configure Nginx, so visit subdomains which should not have SSL (https://www.example.com), it would behave as if the host can not be connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `deny all`, use `return 444` instead.